# state is not updating in react form validation

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am working with simple form validation in react. The problem here is error message is not displaying in  while it is showing in console.log! I am quite new to react and stucked here for quite some time. How can I solve this?

I've seen many youtube videos but nothing is working properly.

```
    const [logindata, setLogindata] = useState({
        customeremail: '',
        customerpass: ''
    })

    const [err, seterr] = useState({
        Email: '',
        Passwordnew: ''
    });

    const handlechange = event => {
        const val = event.target.value
        const name = event.target.name
        setLogindata({ ...logindata, [name]: val })
        console.log(val)

    }

    function login() {
        const NewErr = {...err};
        if (logindata.customeremail == "") {
            NewErr.Email = "Email should not be empty";
            alert(NewErr.Email)
            console.log(NewErr)
        }
    }
  return (
    <>

                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 main-col offset-md-3">
                                <div className="mb-4">
                                    <form method="post" action="home" id="CustomerLoginForm" acceptCharset="UTF-8" className="contact-form">
                                        <div className="row">
                                            <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                                                <div className="form-group">
                                                    <label htmlFor="CustomerEmail">Email</label>
                                                    <input type="email" name="customeremail" placeholder="" id="CustomerEmail" className="" autoCorrect="off" autoCapitalize="off" autoFocus="" onChange={handlechange} value={logindata.customeremail} required = {true} />
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                            {seterr.Email}
                        </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                                                <div className="form-group">
                                                    <label htmlFor="CustomerPassword">Password</label>
                                                    <input type="password" name="customerpass" placeholder="" id="CustomerPassword" className="" onChange={handlechange} value={logindata.customerpass} />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="row">
                                            <div className="text-center col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                                                <input type="button" style={{ backgroundColor: '#000', color: '#fff' }} className="btn mb-3" value="Sign In" onClick={login} />
                                                <p className="mb-4">
                                                    <a href="#" id="RecoverPassword">Forgot your password?</a> &nbsp; | &nbsp;
                                                    <a href="register.html" id="customer_register_link">Create account</a>
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
    </>
```

Comment: Do you want to show an error message under your email input box if there is an error (Email should not be empty)?

Comment: @ArifurRahaman yes

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problem in your code

**`1. Not setting state`**

You are not setting state for `err` using `seterr` as:

```
if (logindata.customeremail == '') {
    NewErr.Email = 'Email should not be empty';
    alert(NewErr.Email);
    console.log(NewErr);
    seterr(NewErr);     // MISSING
}
```

[`CODESANDBOX LINK`](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-kowalevski-sks2v7?file=/src/App.js)

**`2. Showing error message with wrong way`**

> When you use `useState` then it will give you an array of `value` and `function` through which you can update the value and on change of the value it will re-render it. You have to use `err` obj not the function `seterr`.

You should use `{err.Email}}` instead of `{seterr.Email}}`

```
<div className='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
    {/* {seterr.Email} */}
    {err.Email}
</div>;
```